# Is there a global way to merge an iPhone and an iPad app into a universal app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal

I wrote an iPhone app. Then, I changed the interface a fair bit, added higher res images, and made an iPad version of it. In a perfect world, I would like for anyone who buys the iPad version to get the iPhone version for free (though not conversely). Since Apple doesn't seem to have a way to do that (right??), my next favorite solution is to make the iPad version include the iPhone version somehow.

I know that I could just convert the iPad version to "universal", but since the face of the app is so different, that seems like a real pain. I have many view controllers and they are almost completely different between the two versions. Some of the methods are the same, but only about 30%. Is there an easy solution along the lines of this:

- Check if device is iPhone or iPad

  - If iPhone, then use one group of files
  - If iPad, then use a different group of files

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a new project in Xcode and choose to make it a universal app.  In the default way Xcode lays it out, there is a distinct divide between the iPad and iPhone versions.  You can make the two versions of the app as similar or different as you want.

In addition, you can check which device you are running on at runtime by using `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()`. Currently the two values for this are `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad` and `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone`.

Comment: I guess this way I only have to copy over all my files with the correct appending tag. The snag is I have to redo all the damn connections in IB. I suppose this is one argument for doing everything programmatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "easy solution" you describe is basically how iOS loads Universal apps.

There's no other real way around it. You'll have to merge your two projects into one again to do what you want.

The first problem will be that some (many?) names of classes will be common between both projects. You can save yourself some pain by using the "Refactor..." functionality in Xcode to change the names of the classes in one project (say, your iPhone app, since it's older) before you merge them together. The second problem will be your Info.plist; you'll need to ensure that the correct "Main nib file base name", the correct supported interface orientations, icon files, and so on are set to correct values for both iPad and iPhone respectively.